# Set Edge in MigraDoc

Tags: c#, asp.net, migradoc

In migraDoc table i done setedge like

```
t.SetEdge(0, 0, t.Columns.Count, t.Rows.Count, Edge.Box, BorderStyle.Single, 0.5, Colors.Black)
```

It sets the edge for full table. But i dont want edge for firstrow of the table. I tried like

```
t.SetEdge(0, 1, t.Columns.Count, t.Rows.Count, Edge.Box, BorderStyle.Single, 0.5, Colors.Black)
```

But its not working.

Comment: What do you get? What do you expect? What do you get when you don't call SetEdge at all? The problem could be in another line of code.

Answer (score 3):

To set the first row :

```
table.SetEdge(0, 0, table.Columns.Count, 1, Edge.Box, BorderStyle.Single, 2, Colors.Red);
```

note the order is : colBegin, rowBegin, countCols, countRows

I make it red and large to see it well

Comment: Not quite right: parameters are colBegin, rowBegin, countCols, countRows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edge from second row, you have to change the rows param and delete this first row:

```
-t.SetEdge(0, 1, t.Columns.Count, t.Rows.Count-1, Edge.Box, BorderStyle.Single, 0.5, Colors.Black)
```